# Count occurrences of list of strings in text

Tags: python, nltk

I want to count occurrences of list elements in text with Python. I know that I can use `.count()` but I have read that this can effect on performance. Also, element in list can have more than 1 word.

```
my_list = ["largest", "biggest", "greatest", "the best"]

my_text = "i have the biggest house and the biggest car. My friend is the best. Best way win this is to make the largest house and largest treehouse and then you will be the greatest"
```

I can do this:

```
num = 0
for i in my_list:
   num += my_text.lower().count(i.lower())

print(num)
```

This way works, but what If my list has 500 elements and my string is 3000 words, so in that case, I have very low performance.

Is there a way to do this but with good / fast performance?

Comment: For 500 and 3000, I'd expect it to still only take 0.01 seconds. Is that really a problem?

Comment: the problem is that I have dataset of 110K rows with text values, and each row has between 100 and 4000 words. And it takes around 45 minutes to do this. And I have pretty good machine

Comment: If the text is "But the bestiality was bad", do you really want to count "the best" in that?

Comment: And if the text is "the besthe best" or "largesthe best", should that count 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: What if your list contains "buffalo buffalo" and the text is "[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)"? Should it be 4 or 7 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `my_list` contains strings with more than one word, you'll have to find the [`n-grams`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) of `my_text` to find matches, since splitting on spaces won't do. Also note that your approach is not advisable, as for every single string in `my_list`, you'll be traversing the whole string `my_text` by using `count`. A better way would be to predefine the `n-grams` that you'll be looking for beforehand.

Here's one approach using `nltk`'s `ngram`.
I've added another string in `my_list` to better illustrate the process:

```
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

my_list = ["largest", "biggest", "greatest", "the best", 'My friend is the best']
my_text = "i have the biggest house and the biggest car. My friend is the best. Best way win this is to make the largest house and largest treehouse and then you will be the greatest"
```

The first step is to define a dictionary containing the different lengths of the n-grams that we'll be looking up:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in my_list:
    k = i.split()
    d[len(k)].append(tuple(k))

print(d)
defaultdict(list,
            {1: [('largest',), ('biggest',), ('greatest',)],
             2: [('the', 'best')],
             5: [('My', 'friend', 'is', 'the', 'best')]})
```

Then split `my_text` into a list, and for each key in `d` find the corresponding `n-grams` and build a `Counter` from the result. Then for each value in that specific key in `d`, update with the counts from the `Counter`:

```
my_text_split = my_text.replace('.', '').split()
match_counts = dict()
for n,v in d.items():
    c = Counter(ngrams(my_text_split, n))
    for k in v:   
        if k in c:
            match_counts[k] = c[k]
```

Which will give:

```
print(match_counts)

{('largest',): 2,
 ('biggest',): 2,
 ('greatest',): 1,
 ('the', 'best'): 1,
 ('My', 'friend', 'is', 'the', 'best'): 1}
```

Comment: the problem is that I have dataset of 110K rows with text values, and each row has between 100 and 4000 words. And it takes around 45 minutes to do this.

Comment: As heap points out @taga this is a little trickier for strings with >1 words. Will add an update to generalise

Comment: Thanks, will this be effective if I have 500 terms / phrases in the list and 5000 words in the text

Comment: As far as I know, this is the best way to tackle these problems @taga As I mention in the beginning of the answer, this is definitely better than using `count` `len(my_list)` times for larger lists